# Symfony / Service YML : Enum array or object as service parameter

Tags: symfony, yaml, php-8

I have a service defined like this :

```
services: 
    My\Service:
        arguments:
            $myArg: '%app.myParam%'
```

✅ I can pass *one* enum like this, it is working fine.

```
parameters:
    app.myParam: !php/enum MyEnum::Test
```

but when I try to pass enums as array or as object I have an `Warning: Undefined array key "app.myParam"` error

```
parameters:
    app.myParam: [!php/enum MyEnum::Test]
```

```
parameters:
    app.myParam: 
        test: !php/enum MyEnum::Test
```

If I call the parameter directly from the container (getParameter("app.myParam")) I get the array or the object. The issue is only when I use it argument for my service.

Looks like a bug to me.
Can you see if I do something wrong ?